# 5 coloured map being recoloured with 4 colours

Tags: geometry, optimization

Player A is allowed to draw a map with 'n' regions, and colour them in using 5 colours. Two connected regions cannot be of the same colour. This map is then given to Player B, who's job is to recolour the map using only 4 colours (she gets to choose which of the 5 original colours to try to eliminate). Player B's goal is to need to recolour as few regions as possible. Player A is trying to create a map which maximises the number of regions which require recolouring.

For instance, with n=10, I think this is the best Player A can do:

[image]

In this map, the yellow and blue regions are isomorphic. Suppose Player B recolours the yellow regions. Both yellow regions are in contact with regions of each of the other four colours. It requires four regions to be recoloured, for instance:

[image]

You will find similarly that choosing any other colour to eliminate means 4 regions will need to be recoloured.

Question: what is the relationship between 'n', the number of regions on the map, and C, the number of recolourings required (assuming both Players A and B are playing optimally)? Is it the case that C = approx 2n/5 ?

Comment: Heuristically: Assume we have a map that is extremely hard to 4-colour (i.e., the only choice you have is permuting colours), but easily 5-colourable (i.e., almost every assignment of 5 colours is valid). Then only about $n/5$ regions can keep their colour. That seems to be a lower bound

Comment: n/5 is a lower bound for how many regions need to be recoloured: If player A uses the 5 colours equally, then whichever colour B chooses to eliminate will require at least n/5 recolourings. But are you saying that 4n/5 is the upper bound for how many recolourings are required? I'd agree, but its a very generous upper bound.